# Sorting a multi-dimensional array based on a consistent array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array value based on a consistent key. My array looks something similar to this and the key I want to sort values in order by is `discipline_one`.

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'score' => 200,
        'results' => [
            'discipline_one' => "4:01"
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'score' => 250,
        'results' => [
            'discipline_one' => "3:50"
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'score' => 284,
        'results' => [
            'discipline_one' => "3:42"
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'score' => 300,
        'results' => [
            'discipline_one' => "4:27"
        ],
    ],
];
```

Going off the `id` key in the above example, my expected output would be in the order:

```
3, 2, 1, 4
```

Previously, to query based on `score` I used:

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'score'), SORT_DESC, $data);
```

However, if [I add an additional](https://3v4l.org/msgAD) `array_column` on this for the `discipline_one` consistent key then I get:

```
array_multisort(array_column(array_column($data, 'result'), 'discipline_one'), SORT_DESC, $data);
```

> array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

The third argument expects the same array which in this case is not possible. Does any one know a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Your array has a column `'results'` and you have `'result'` in your code to extract the column.

Comment: This is true, I moved it over from my actual data in a more confined environment for SO so I produced a typo. The method still produces the issue and doesn't work so no, this problem is still reproducible and was not only caused by a typo. @NigelRen

Comment: I have just tried the code with 'results' and get the order I would expect - 4, 1, 2, 3

Comment: [I cannot reproduce if I use a greater number](https://3v4l.org/aSBcF) @NigelRen

Comment: Try the accepted answer with the same values!  You are comparing strings and not times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using simple `usort`?

```
usort($data, fn($a, $b) => ($a['results']['discipline_one'] <=> $b['results']['discipline_one']) * -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I really appreciate this, I have not seen `<=>` before I will definitely look into this! I'll accept this answer once the time allows me too.

Comment: @Jaquarh That's `spaceship operator`, but you can return any _below 0_, _0_ or _above 0_ number in any sort function

Comment: Testing large data, I also see that the issue I have is that it is a string due to the `:` so the comparison is very weird when working with `1:55` and `11:55`. It shows `11:55` before `1:55` so to this end I will remove the `:` and convert to integer before checking.

Comment: If you swap the $a and $b round you can avoid having to use `* -1`